# Hibernate hql elements

Tags: hibernate

I  created a hibernate program and wrote a query and got the following error:

I got an exception stating `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double`

```
String qry="Select Distinct (s2Taxper) from S2 where s2Tc='601' AND s2Txcd!=''";
Iterator atItr2=hbSession.createQuery(qry).iterate();
String qry1="Select ahCode,ahName,ahRcNumber,ahCentralSalesTaxNumber From AccountHeader ORDER    BY  ahName ASC";

Iterator atItr1=hbSession.createQuery(qry1).iterate();

mainBean=new VatMainBean();

VatSubBeanList=new ArrayList<VatSubBean>();

while(atItr1.hasNext()){
    subBean=new VatSubBean();

    Object[] obj1=(Object[])atItr1.next();

    String ahCode  =(String)obj1[0];                                         
    String ahName  =(String)obj1[1];                                         
    String ahRcNumber=(String)obj1[2];                                        
    String ahCentralSalesTaxNumber=(String)obj1[3];

    if("v".equalsIgnoreCase(type)){
        if(ahRcNumber!=null&&!"".equalsIgnoreCase(ahRcNumber)){
            if(ahRcNumber.indexOf("/")<0&&ahRcNumber.indexOf(":")<0&&ahRcNumber.indexOf(" ")<0){
                //buyersTinNo.trim();
                if(ahRcNumber.length()==11){
                    buyersTinNo=ahRcNumber;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        if(ahCentralSalesTaxNumber!=null&&!"".equalsIgnoreCase(ahCentralSalesTaxNumber)){
            buyersTinNo=ahCentralSalesTaxNumber;
        }
    }

    DoubleCheck doubleObj1=new DoubleCheck();

    List<String> taxPerList=new ArrayList<String>(); 

    int i = 0;
    while (atItr2.hasNext()){
        Object[] obj2=(Object[])atItr2.next();// error is shown here

        String s2Taxper=(String)obj2[0];

        int s1Docno=(Integer)obj2[1];

        if(Double.parseDouble(s2Taxper)>0){
            taxPerList.add(s2Taxper);
        }
```

How do I rectify this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of you fileds is double and you try to cast it to string.
Look on the coulmn defintion.
If you want to convert double to string you should do this by Double.tostring

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code...

```
String qry="Select Distinct (s2Taxper) from S2 where s2Tc='601' AND s2Txcd!=''";
// ....
Iterator atItr2=hbSession.createQuery(qry).iterate();
// ....
while (atItr2.hasNext()){
    Object[] obj2=(Object[])atItr2.next();// error is shown here
}
```

It's clear that what you are trying to cast as `Object[]` is basically a `S2` and hence the error.